# Why doesn't show the changes in output(browser preview) in Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I have a problem regarding angular. So I started creating a sample website.

My problem is though I have coded correctly and compiled it successfully the output that means the preview of the website not shows the changes.

One day ago I added a change in my code but that day it didn't appear .But fortunately today when I run that code without changes it showed the changes what I was expected one day ago.

Please tell me how can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of the cache. Disable the cache on your chrome devetools (in network tab). Best way to test your app is in incognito mode (private navigation) so no cache is stored from session to session.

Also you could register a service worker and notify the user when change is made to the app so they could refresh the app. Read more about service workers [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

If you don't see the changes locally, then you could try to stop the app and compile/serve it again.